# How to print comparison matrix in python?

Tags: python

Do you probably know how I can print a comparison matrix in python, I have 5 variables, I apply T test(defined a function as ttest to apply the T test between 2 data samples) on them one by one and get 10 comparison results, now I want to visualize the results just like correlation matrix or a table, to visualize the results. the columns and rows labels will be the same 5 variables and the comparison result between each variables will be filled in the table. If there is no such function in python maybe some latex code will also be good.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incredibly unclear but I think I can see vaguely what you want...

So you have a `list` (or some other data type) which contains `5` elements and want to apply some `function` to every combination of `2` elements.

We can achieve this with `itertools.combination`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [4, 5, 5, 7, 9]
>>> list(itertools.combinations(l, 2))
[(4, 5), (4, 5), (4, 7), (4, 9), (5, 5), (5, 7), (5, 9), (5, 7), (5, 9), (7, 9)]
```

As you can see, we now have access to the `10` different combinations.

So let's pretend your function was simply something like a sum:

```
def add(a, b):
     return a + b
```

We could now apply this function to every combination and output the results to a new `list` with a `list-comprehension`:

```
[add(*c) for c in itertools.combinations(l, 2)]
```

which, for our example, gives:

```
[9, 9, 11, 13, 10, 12, 14, 12, 14, 16]
```

which is correct.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous statement, but I am actually looking for a table, to visualize the results. the columns and rows labels will be the same 5 variables and the comparison result between each variables will be filled in the table.

Comment: But that won't produce a neat results as there will be `25` cells in the table (`5x5` ) and there are only `10` unique combinations.

Comment: yes, it will be half correlation matrix and without the diagonal